# Retrieve relationship objects between two models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's assume that there are two models defined in SQLAlchemy:

User:

```
class User(db.Model):
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

Product:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[user_id], backref='products')
    created_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    created_by_user = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[created_by])
```

It there any other way to retrieve all relationships in pattern: `Product -> User` than this:

```
fk_mapper = Product.__mapper__
fk_relationships = list(fk_mapper.relationships)
product_user_rels = [item for item in fk_relationships if item.mapper.class_ is User]
```

This feels a bit clumsy.

Comment: Not sure if it is really more elegant but you can use [`inspect`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html) in a similar way

Comment: Yes that is correct, but I'm afraid that `inspect` method is not production friendly.